# How to save a GIF with transparency without it creating white blobs around glow? Open for other solutions!

Tags: png, gif

So, basically, I have a website where I want to put animated christmas lights, nothing to complex.

Note: Don't mind the watermarks, they are just in case...

I made the static image in png first:

Static image: [image]

All ok with that, it display correctly in the website

Then, I tried animating it to gif, in photoshop, and the image was ruined:

Settings: [image]

Final result: [http://i.imgur.com/NlQf5VM.gif](https://i.imgur.com/NlQf5VM.gif)

So, basically, I just want to know what are all the possible ways of making this animation show in my website, good quality, without white blobs or any blobs at all, and with transparency.

I will really accept any options, gif, video, flash, anything. I would just like to have this on a website.

Note: This is above a slideshow, so, making it match the background is not an option, at all.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: GIF does not support semi-transparency - you need to dither for fake semi-transparent GIFs. See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/gif-with-transparency-output-not-as-expected-in-gimp.

Comment: That will make it look really bad, with bad quality, do you know any other ways of getting the same result? Like, with flash or html5? Something? I am just not experienced in those areas so I don't know...

Comment: Why can't you use a png?

Comment: I need it to be animated, png is static... I want christmas lights that are actually animated

Comment: you may find alternatives to GIF here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90/what-formats-supporting-animation-are-suitable-for-the-web - consider a Java scripted PNG slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

Gif will not support multi-level transparency. Use PNG 24 bit. But be warned, it comes at the price of a larger file size.

Comment: OP wants to make a animation so your answer wont directly work.

Comment: This is a PNG and animated. https://people.mozilla.org/~dolske/apng/chompy.png (source: https://people.mozilla.org/~dolske/apng/demo.html)